# Querying XML and updating certain elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file in the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AA someattrib="xyz">
    <BB someOtherAttrib="xyz">
    <Title></Title>
        <CC>

            <myNode rowid="">
                <subNode1></subNode1>
                <subNode2></subNode2>
                <nodeOfInterest></nodeOfInterest>
            </myNode >
            <myNode rowid="">
                <subNode1> </subNode1>

            </myNode>
        </CC>
    </BB>
</AA>
```

I want to use Linq to pick out one node by the name 'MyNode' where the rowid is a particular number that I will be getting from a collection in an object. Once I get myNode I want to update the value of the child nodeOfInterest if it is present. If not present, then I would like to add it. Once done I want to save the file.

This is what I have at the moment but it may not be the right approach.

```
    foreach (User employee in Users)
    {

        XPathNavigator node = xNav.SelectSingleNode("/AA/BB/CC/myNode[@rowid = '"+employee.ID.ToString()+"']");
        XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator= node.SelectChildren("nodeOfInterest", "");
        if (nodeIterator.Count == 1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

Is there a way this can be done using a direct join between the List and the xmldoc in memory? This will be a large list and an equally large xml file. I dont think running a loop and calling selectSingleNode is the most efficient way.

Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer, with help from Jon's replies...

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("thefile.xml");
var dictionary = doc.Element("AA").Element("BB").Element("CC").Elements("myNode")
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("rowId").Value);

foreach (User employee in Users)
{
    XElement myNode;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(employee.ID, out myNode))
    {
            XElement nodeOfInterest = myNode.Elements("nodeOfInterest").FirstOrDefault();
            if (nodeOfInterest != null)
            {
                nodeOfInterest.Value = "update with this value";
            }
            else
            {
                XElement nodeOfInterest = new XElement("nodeOfInterest", "Add nodeOfInterest with this value");
                myNode.Add(newElement);
            }
    }

}
doc.Save("TheFile.xml");
```

Comment: where does the `element` come from it was never declared

Comment: element should be myNode, I believe

Answer (score 2):

Well one starting point would be to create a `Dictionary<string, XElement>` mapping the row ID to the element:

```
var dictionary = doc.Element("AA").Element("BB").Element("CC").Elements("myNode")
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("rowId").Value);
```

Then:

```
foreach (User employee in Users)
{
    XElement myNode;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(employee.ID, out myNode))
    {
        // Use myNode
    }
    else
    {
        // Employee not found
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer using the selection methods provided by LINQ to XML (`Elements`, `Element`, `Descendants` etc) rather than `SelectSingleNode`, `SelectChildren` etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm still not able to update the [elementofInterest] node or add a new one and then save the entire document with the updated/added [elementofInterest] nodes to the file system once done.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm still not able to" - what happens when you try? It should be absolutely fine.

Comment: If I understood this right, the if block will have the entire [myNode] node. Once I have this entire node in the variable myNode, I still need to check if the element  [elementofInterest] exists and if it does, I need to update it, if not, I need to add one. This needs to be done for the number of iterations in the loop and then the document needs to be saved

Comment: @user20358: Right, so that's easy enough to do - just use `myNode.Elements("somename")` to get the relevant children. You can use `Any()` to check if there are any, for example. I'm not going to write all the code for you - and your question seemed to really be about finding the `myNode` element efficiently, which I've answered.

Comment: Perhaps I did not frame my question right. There were three things I needed help with. Find, update/add, save. I should have put that at the end instead of putting it before the for loop in the question. Thanks for the hint on the Find bit. I will work with that.

Comment: @user20358: If you have several problems, you should ask several questions - but make sure you do appropriate research on each one. (Your questions shouldn't just be "here's what I want to do - please write the code for me" for example.)

Comment: What I had put up was the furthest I had gone with my research. I did not want to influence the direction in which the answers from respondents go, with my incorrect attempts. I have noticed people give more clearer replies if you don't muddle their thoughts with your faulty attempts. I agree on asking multiple questions, however, I did not think it would help in this case.

Comment: @user20358: No, you should almost *always* show what you've tried so far, and explain in what way it doesn't work for you. Otherwise people may go over ground you've already covered, or you can give the impression that you're treating SO as a code-writing service - neither of which is good.